# my computer kept on rebooting because of the deep freeze

Tags: windows-7

I tried all that is written here about <kbd>F8</kbd>, safe mode W command prompt etc., but my computer still continues to unstoppable booting because of deep freeze and windows update. i have Windows 7, please help, are there other ways in order to stop it from booting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use something like [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/)? It might be just that one of your memory sticks are bad, also is this a custom built PC?